# Can a junction table attribute be used as foreign key in another table?

Tags: sql, relational-database, entity-relationship

Suppose I have a table patients and a table tests. Patients can take many tests and tests are given to many patients. so it's a many to many relationship. I create a junction table between them. I also want to store the date the patient wants to take the tests so I do that in the junction table. Also, suppose a patient takes more than 1 test on a single day and I want to create a specific billing account against all the test on that date.

I create an autogenerated billing no. I add that to the junction table as well.

So far, my junction table record the tests a patient may have taken on a date and the billing no.

Now I create a table `billingaccounts`. In this table I want to store all the billing information against 1 billing No. such as totalamount, paid amount and so on. I also want to include the billing no here, since it will help me identify the patient and tests the billing account field refers to.

I was trying to make the billing no in this billing account table as a foreign key to the billing no in the previous junction table.

But I can't do that since the billing no in the junction table cannot be kept unique since it's an m:n junction table.

What can I do to make this work or any other alternatives?

Comment: You may want to move this to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a primary key column to the "junction" table.  Your junction table is richer than simply matching two tables.  Because you want a foreign key relationship, it is worthy of its own primary key.  For example (using MySQL syntax):

```
create table PatientTests (
    PatientTestId int primary key auto_increment,
    PatientId int not null,
    TestId int not null,
    TestDate date,
    BillingAccount int,
    . . .
    constraint fk_patienttests_patientid references Patients(PatientId),
    . . .
);
```

create table

Answer (score 0):

Make the `billing no` in the junction table a foreign key to the primary key of the `billingaccounts` table. So, you would create a new row in `billingacounts` first, including an autogenerated id/billing no, then use that number in the junction table.